# dot net sdk 5.0 on ubuntu

Tags: dotnet

I've found and used this :  https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/5.0/preview/5.0.0-rc.2-install-instructions.md

to no avail. I can't get a install of .net sdk 5.0 on ubuntu

I try to run a simple Blazor project, I get this :

```
dotnet-sdk.dotnet electronize init
It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
The framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '3.1.0' was not found.
  - The following frameworks were found:
      5.0.0-rc.2.20475.5 at [/snap/dotnet-sdk/103/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

You can resolve the problem by installing the specified framework and/or SDK.

The specified framework can be found at:
  - https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.NETCore.App&framework_version=3.1.0&arch=x64&rid=ubuntu.20.04-x64
```

Comment: looks like the blazor project is wanting .NETCore 3.1.0 not 5.0.0.  You DO have a 5.0.0 install - it even shows it was identified and found.  What the app you're working with is looking for is **`3.1.0`** not 5.0

Comment: you're right I think. thanks. it's the project that's wrong, I do want to be in 5.0 version. I'm going to try and fix the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *already have* a 5.0.0 environment, and `dotnet` even detects it, as shown in your output:

```
  - The following frameworks were found:
      5.0.0-rc.2.20475.5 at [/snap/dotnet-sdk/103/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

Your problem isn't that you don't have a 5.0.0 environment, it's that the project you're working with wants an older version, **`3.1.0`** specifically.

So the problem isn't that you don't have 5.0.0 installed but that your project just doesn't work with 5.0.0